# What is this formula called? summation

Tags: summation

[image: some summation formula]

Does people know what this formula called? I want to google its properties and read about it more - if it has official name

Comment: In some contexts this can be the convex hull of the set of points {$(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$}, i.e., the set of points with the conditions you gave is the smallest convex set containing the points {$(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a "weighted average" or "weighted mean". The numbers $\mu_i$ are called the "weights".

Comment: For the OP:  the weights do not necessarily have to add to $1$ for a general weighted average.

Comment: thanks a lot, i go google it